# What is this 4x4 board game?

Tags: identify-this-game

This board game has been circling around the office and nobody knows what it is.

This is what we know:

- 4x4
- 8 pieces
- The pieces change colour depending on in what direction and on what tile you place them
- If you place the piece in the same direction but on another tile it changes colour
- All pieces seem to show the same colour when placed on the same tile in the same direction
- There are 4 colours: Red, green, yellow and purple
- Made by All in 1 products Ltd. in China 2005

  [image]

What is this game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Sata](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/29417/sata) (released in some countries as Tactigo).

Comment: The goal is "a straight line of three pieces in a row that show the same color in their windows"